# Silent Phone Launcher Icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am working on an app where, I am controlling `phone` volume etc sound related things ,designer create application logo without any background, when I am using that `icon` on `phone` it showing some `background` as in attachment **"Silent Phone"** with red line,how we can handle this case ? I did test on `Samsung Galaxy-S3` and `HTC V one` , both showing issue.

[image]

[image: "]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the image, there is no problem with your Image, please make sure that you have this configuration when you have added your image, to test create a new empty project as the joined image: 
[image]

Its how it looks on my HTC DESIRE :
[image: image luncher icon]

Comment: Hi with that is great,with new project its working fine,but when I change icon image in existing project and replace that with new one it showing as I post above ..Thanks . .